# Dereferencing the integer value of a for loop in java

Tags: java, for-loop, dereference

I just figured out that when I do this in Java:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
{
    String bla = "bla";
    bla += x.toString();
}
```

It (Netbeans in this case) will tell me I can not dereference my x integer in such a manner (as I would in C#).

Why is that?

Comment: Just to check, does the code compile and run?

Comment: there is no `toString()` for int but in your case, you can do `bla += x;`

Comment: It does compile and run in C# yes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Primitive types are not objects in Java, so you need to use other methods to do that, in this case:

```
Integer.toString(x);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. This has answered my question

Answer (score 7):

an int is a primitive, not an Object, and hence does not have a toString() method.

But you can do this:

```
String bla = "bla" + x;
```

Answer (score 5):

`int` is not an object, but a primitive type.  Thus, you cannot call methods off of `int`.  If you defined it as `Integer`, the error message would go away.  However, you can really just get rid of `toString`, because `x` will be coerced into a `String` automatically.

Answer (score 4):

x is not an `Integer`, its an `int`, and `int` is a primitive type, so it doesn't have `toString`.

Answer (score 4):

You declared `x` to be of type `int` which is a primitive value, not an object.  Primitives cannot have methods (like `toString()`) called on them.  You could use the primitive wrapper `Integer` if you want to invoke `toString()`, or you could simply remove the call to `toString()` and Java's special handling of strings and primitives will take care of itself.

Answer (score 3):

In java, primitive types (boolean int, short, char,long, float, double) are NOT objects.

They however do have wrapper type (Integer, Character, ...) which have 1) utilyty static functions and 2) its instances can wrap primitive values.

Comment: Exactly, which is why any C# will come to this question: since the wrapper type automatically boxes the primitive, and the wrapper has a toString(), why then isn't x.toString() valid? x should box to Integer and Integer has a toString(). So the answer isn't really that an int is a primitive (it is in c# as well as he points out), but the question is "why is javas autoboxing not doing what the .net autoboxing does".

Comment: That is indeed exactly what I wanted to know

Comment: I thought that in .NET int actualy is object, so x.toString() does not involve autoboxing at all. But it is value object, so where reference object is needed, autoboxing get involved.